# how do i add 1 to an integer from another class every time a method is called?

Tags: java, android

I have a class that has an integer called counter. I have displayed this integer in a text view in the main activity. I also want a thing to happen when the planetClick method happens. I want it so it adds 1 to the counter integer every time the planetClick method is called.  I also want the counter integer to be the same value in every object and i want it displayed in the text view as the same value as well so i used static, is that what im meant to do?

My Class below

```
 public class Ship implements Serializable {

        private static int counter = 1;
        public int getCounter()
        {
            return counter;
        }
        public void setCounter(int c) {
            counter = c;
        }
}
```

Main activity below

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

       TextView counterText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);

       counterText.setText(String.valueOf(new Ship().getCounter()));
    }
    public void planetClick(View view)
    {
      //I want to add 1 to the counter integer here
    }
```

***----edit----***

@Sagar Pilkhwal

here is my code that i used from your answer, What am i doing wrong?:

Main activity below

```
 private Ship  mShip;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        mShip  = new Ship();
        TextView counterText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);

        counterText.setText(String.valueOf(mShip.getCounter()));
    }

    public void planetClick(View view)
    {
        int curCounter = mShip.getCounter();
        mShip.setCounter(curCounter + 1);

    }
```

Comment: Make ship as a class variable, add a addCounter  method to ship and use it in planetClick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private Ship mShip;
private TextView counterText;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    mShip = new Ship();
    counterText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
    counterText.setText(String.valueOf(mShip.getCounter()));
}
public void planetClick(View view) {
    int curCounter = mShip.getCounter();
    mShip.setCounter(curCounter + 1);
    counterText.setText(String.valueOf(mShip.getCounter()));
}
```

Comment: hey i have edited the question with right answer by its not getting updated as it required peer review, do refer the comment above it will surely work

Comment: Thanks the comment with the code above this one fixed it. Thanks :)!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to make the getter and setter for the counter static as well. That way you won't have to create a new instance of Ship every time you want to increment it.

```
public static int getCounter() ...
public static void setCounter(int c) ...
...
// to update the counter from another class
Ship.setCounter(Ship.getCounter() + 1);
```

In the interests of good object-orientated practice, you could have `Ship` provide an `incrementCounter()` method rather than a `setCounter()` method.

I would say that if you have a truly global counter it would make sense to keep it inside the class from which it is used, then you could just have a static int, and increment it with `counter++`.

Answer (score 1):

In the `planetClick` method, add this:

```
Ship.setCounter(Ship.getCounter() + 1);
```

This will add 1 to `counter`. Also, you do not have to make `counter` static because it is private and is not being referenced from any static methods within the `Ship` class, but you need to make `getCounter` and `setCounter` static for this to work.

Comment: This will not work unless setCounter() and getCounter() are static.

Comment: Yes, so they need to be made static.

Answer (score 0):

Your getter and setter should be static since it is a static field. However, since it is a primitive type and that your getter and setter do not process anything particular, I would recommend you to make your counter public so you can access it very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `counter` variable `public` instead of `private`. Change its declaration to:

```
public static int counter = 1;
```

Then inside your `planetClick()` method, add this line:

```
Ship.counter++;
```

That will increment the `counter` variable by one every time `planetClick()` is called.